# How to fix "error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: { path }\PinCode\index.ts: Exporting local "IPinCodeParams", which is not declared." in React-Native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, syntax-error, upgrade, babeljs

I created a new project. I have special folders for interfaces, types and etc. I will have a lot of them, so I import them into one file and export them from there. When I want to export multiple interfaces I get an error:

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: C:\Users\QWERTY\Desktop\TestProjects\2019\TestProject\node_modules\react-native\scripts\src\types\PinCode\index.ts: Exporting local "IPinCodeParams", which is not declared.
  13 | }
  14 |
> 15 | export { PinStatus, IPinCodeParams }
     |                     ^
    at File.buildCodeFrameError (C:\Users\QWERTY\Desktop\TestProjects\2019\TestProject\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\transformation\file\file.js:261:12)
    at NodePath.buildCodeFrameError (C:\Users\QWERTY\Desktop\TestProjects\2019\TestProject\node_modules\@babel\traverse\lib\path\index.js:157:21)
    at getLocalMetadata (C:\Users\QWERTY\Desktop\TestProjects\2019\TestProject\node_modules\@babel\helper-module-transforms\lib\normalize-and-load-metadata.js:281:22)
    at child.get.forEach.spec (C:\Users\QWERTY\Desktop\TestProjects\2019\TestProject\node_modules\@babel\helper-module-transforms\lib\normalize-and-load-metadata.js:315:11)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at programPath.get.forEach.child (C:\Users\QWERTY\Desktop\TestProjects\2019\TestProject\node_modules\@babel\helper-module-transforms\lib\normalize-and-load-metadata.js:307:33)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at getLocalExportMetadata (C:\Users\QWERTY\Desktop\TestProjects\2019\TestProject\node_modules\@babel\helper-module-transforms\lib\normalize-and-load-metadata.js:294:27)
    at getModuleMetadata (C:\Users\QWERTY\Desktop\TestProjects\2019\TestProject\node_modules\@babel\helper-module-transforms\lib\normalize-and-load-metadata.js:86:21)
```

I have this folder structure:

```
android\
ios\
node_modules\
src\
--->constants\
       |--->colors.ts
       |--->fonts.ts
       |--->index.ts
--->router\
       |--->index.ts
--->screen\
       |--->Splash\
               |--->containers\
                      |--->index.ts
                      |--->SplashContainer.tsx
               |--->views\
                      |--->index.ts
                      |--->SplashView.tsx
               |--->index.tsx
       |--->index.ts
--->types\
       |--->PinCode\
               |--->index.tsx
       |--->index.tsx
--->App.tsx
.babelrc
*
*
*
package.json
rn-cli.config.js
tsconfig.json
tslint.json
```

In the file **"PinCode"** I have an enum and an interface.

When I write so (all right):

```
export enum PinStatus {
  New = 'new',
  Confirm = 'confirm',
  Unlock = 'unlock',
  Edit = 'edit',
}

export interface IPinCodeParams {
  status: PinStatus;
  onComplete: () => void;
  onClose?: () => void;
  originalCode?: string;
}
```

But when I write so (I get the error):

```
enum PinStatus {
  New = 'new',
  Confirm = 'confirm',
  Unlock = 'unlock',
  Edit = 'edit',
}

interface IPinCodeParams {
  status: PinStatus;
  onComplete: () => void;
  onClose?: () => void;
  originalCode?: string;
}

export { PinStatus, IPinCodeParams };
```

I have created some completely new projects, tried to rewrite this project several times, but nothing came out. I finally got this error anyway.

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "TestProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-android",
    "ios": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js run-ios",
    "lint": "yarn tslint && yarn typecheck",
    "tslint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json --config tslint.json src/**/*.ts{,x} --format stylish",
    "typecheck": "tsc --project tsconfig.json --noEmit",
    "postinstall": "typesync",
    "type-sync": "typesync"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "yarn lint",
      "pre-push": "yarn lint"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mobx": "^4.9.2",
    "mobx-persist": "^0.4.1",
    "mobx-react": "^5.4.3",
    "react": "16.8.0",
    "react-native": "0.58.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.2.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.3.0",
    "@types/babel-core": "6.25.5",
    "@types/jest": "24.0.0",
    "@types/prettier": "^1.16.0",
    "@types/react": "16.8.2",
    "@types/react-native": "0.57.34",
    "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.4",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.0.1",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.8.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "24.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.3",
    "husky": "^1.3.1",
    "jest": "24.1.0",
    "jsc-android": "236355.1.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.51.1",
    "mobx-logger": "^0.7.1",
    "prettier": "^1.16.4",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.11",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.6.3",
    "tslint": "^5.12.1",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18.0",
    "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
    "tslint-react": "^3.6.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.4",
    "typesync": "^0.4.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset",
  ],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
      {
        "legacy": true
      }
    ],
    "@babel/transform-react-jsx-source",
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        "root": [
          "/src"
        ],
        "alias": {
          "@api": "./src/api",
          "@actions": "./src/actions",
          "@components": "./src/components",
          "@constants": "./src/constants",
          "@hocs": "./src/hocs",
          "@managers": "./src/managers",
          "@locales": "./src/locales",
          "@reducers": "./src/reducers",
          "@screens": "./src/screens",
          "@static": "./src/static",
          "@stores": "./src/stores",
          "@styles": "./src/styles",
          "@types": "./src/types",
          "@utils": "./src/utils"
        }
      }
    ],
  ]
}
```

**tsconfing.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "jsx": "react-native",
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "paths": {
      "@api": [
        "api"
      ],
      "@actions": [
        "actions"
      ],
      "@components": [
        "components"
      ],
      "@constants": [
        "constants"
      ],
      "@hocs": [
        "hocs"
      ],
      "@managers": [
        "managers"
      ],
      "@locales": [
        "locales"
      ],
      "@reducers": [
        "reducers"
      ],
      "@screens": [
        "screens"
      ],
      "@static": [
        "static"
      ],
      "@stores": [
        "stores"
      ],
      "@styles": [
        "styles"
      ],
      "@types": [
        "types"
      ],
      "@utils": [
        "utils"
      ]
    }
  },
}
```

**tslist.json**

```
{
  "defaultSeverity": "error",
  "extends": [
    "tslint-config-prettier",
    "tslint-eslint-rules",
    "tslint-react",
    "tslint:latest"
  ],
  "jsRules": {},
  "rules": {
    "await-promise": false,
    "interface-over-type-literal": false,
    "jsx-alignment": true,
    "jsx-boolean-value": false,
    "jsx-no-bind": true,
    "jsx-no-lambda": false,
    "max-classes-per-file": false,
    "member-access": false,
    "member-ordering": false,
    "no-constant-condition": false,
    "no-duplicate-imports": false,
    "no-empty": false,
    "no-implicit-dependencies": false,
    "no-submodule-imports": false,
    "object-literal-sort-keys": false,
    "ordered-imports": false,
    "quotemark": [
      true,
      "single",
      "jsx-single",
      "avoid-escape"
    ],
    "semicolon": [
      true,
      "always"
    ],
    "trailing-comma": [
      true,
      {
        "singleline": "never",
        "multiline": "always"
      }
    ],
    "triple-equals": [
      true,
      "allow-undefined-check"
    ]
  },
  "linterOptions": {
    "exclude": [
      "./src/typings/**/*.d.ts"
    ]
  },
  "rulesDirectory": []
}
```

[Reference to the source project (Github)](https://github.com/SergeyMyssak/TestProject)

Why do I get this error? How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you write your answer inside your own question:

```js
export enum PinStatus {
  New = 'new',
  Confirm = 'confirm',
  Unlock = 'unlock',
  Edit = 'edit',
}

export interface IPinCodeParams {
  status: PinStatus;
  onComplete: () => void;
  onClose?: () => void;
  originalCode?: string;
}
```